# 5 people needs to perform 4 different tasks in pairs. find all combinations as every person must do at least 1 task

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion

$5$ people needs to preform $4$ different tasks in pairs.
each pair is allowed to preform more then 1 task (it's possible that 1 pair preforms all 4 tasks).

> 1. Find the number of all possible pairs exists to preform the tasks exists?
> 2. Find the number of all possible pairs exists to preform all tasks, as each person must preform **at least** 1 task. Use inclusion and exclusion.

***My Attempt:***

1. There are $5$ people and $4$ tasks, so for each task we have $\binom{5}{2}$ possibilities, in total, there are $\binom{5}{2}^4$   combinations.
2. Let the number of all pairs preforming all tasks be $A$, and let $B$ be the set of all pairs preforming the tasks as all $5$ people must be participating in at least one task.

that means that:

If $3$ people are preforming $2$ tasks, then $3$ people are preforming $1$ tasks

If $2$ people are preforming $3$ tasks, then $3$ people are preforming $1$ tasks

If $1$ person is preforming $4$ tasks, then $4$ people are preforming $1$ tasks.

I don't understand how to convert that into math.

For section (1) I did:
$x_1 + x_2 +x_3 +x_4 = 5$, therefore the number of all natural solutions for that is equals to $\binom{5}{2}^4$.

that does that means that for section (2) I'd have to find all natrual solutions for the equation, such that $\forall x \in {x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4}: x \neq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us number the tasks by $1,2,3,4$ and the persons by $1,2,3,4,5$.

In the first part we actually calculate the number of functions: $$\left\{ 1,2,3,4\right\} \to \left\{ \left\{ i,j\right\} \mid i,j\in\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5\right\} \text{ and }i\neq j\right\} $$

Denote this set of functions by $F$.

For $i=1,2,3,4,5$ let $F_{i}\subseteq F$
denote the subset of functions corresponding with *person $i$ doing
no task*.

That means that: $$F_{i}=\left\{ f\in F\mid i\notin f\left(1\right)\cup f\left(2\right)\cup f\left(3\right)\cup f\left(4\right)\right\} $$

Then to be found is: $$\left|\bigcap_{i=1}^{5}F_{i}^{\complement}\right|=\left|F\right|-\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{5}F_{i}\right|=\binom{5}{2}^{4}-\binom{5}{1}\left|F_{1}\right|+\binom{5}{2}\left|F_{1}\cap F_{2}\right|-\binom{5}{3}\left|F_{1}\cap F_{2}\cap F_{3}\right|$$

Here $F_1\cap F_2\cap F_3\cap F_4$ and $F_1\cap F_2\cap F_3\cap F_4\cap F_5$ are both empty because for a task you need at least $2$ person.

Can you take it from here?